# Validating StringField based on input in a separate Field on WTForms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

i am working on a Form whereby a user can manage the inventory of a business. Specifically, i want to be able to add a certain amount of stock in a StringField, while in a separate StringField - be able to add in the amount of sales not exceeding the amount of stock added.

I would also like to know if it would be possible to make users input numbers only in the fields. I have tried using IntegerField but it ends up with a Name Error stating that IntegerField is not recognised.

```
from wtforms import Form, StringField, RadioField, SelectField, TextAreaField, validators
class CreateGPUForm(Form):
    GPUBrand = SelectField('GPU Brand',default='NVIDIA' ,choices=[('NVIDIA', 'NVIDIA'),('MSI/Micro Star International', 'MSI/Micro Star International'),('Zotac', 'Zotac'),('EVGA', 'EVGA'),('Galax', 'Galax'),('Power Color', 'Power Color'),('Sapphire', 'Sapphire')], render_kw={'readonly': False})
    GPUName = StringField('GPU Name/Series', [validators.Length(min=1), validators.DataRequired()], render_kw={'readonly': False})
    GPUStock = IntegerField('Enter GPU Stock To Add', [validators.Length(min=1), validators.DataRequired()])
    GPUUnitPrice = StringField('GPU Manufacturing Price', [validators.Length(min=1), validators.DataRequired()], render_kw={'readonly': False})
    GPUSalePrice = StringField('GPU Retail Price', [validators.Length(min=1), validators.DataRequired()], render_kw={'readonly': False})
    GPUSales = StringField('Amount of GPUs Sold', [validators.Length(min=1), validators.DataRequired()], render_kw={'readonly': False})
```

Answer (score 0):

To have client side validation before submitting to the server you will need to use Javascript.

If you want to do server side validation after the user has submitted the form (so that you can resend error on a refreshed form) you can edit the validate hook:

```
class CreateGPUForm(Form):
    # ...
    def validate(self):
        """Overwrite the Base validation function"""
        rv = Form.validate(self)
        if not rv:
            return False

        # now custom validation code:
        if self.GPUSales.data > self.GPUStock.data:
            self.GPUSales.errors.append('There is not enough stock...') 
            return False
        return True
```

There is an IntegerField but you have not imported it. Look in the WTF docs